# A serviceman wanted to repair my faulty laptop keyboard by exchanging the SSD

Tags: laptop, ssd, keyboard, lenovo-laptop, laptop-repair

I have the laptop Lenovo Ideapad 720 15IKB and run OpenSUSE on it. Since the beginning of the new year I started having problems with the **columns 6YHN** (often) and **7UJM** (less often). Sometimes they do not work and I have to press them many times, using a lot of pressure and trying different angles. Sometimes it helps that I put pressure on the corners of the laptop. I have the feeling that it is a **mechanical problem,** possibly with the cable connecting the keyboard to the motherboard.

The last week I gave the laptop to a **service** and after a **"diagnosis"** (which I was told involved "professional tools" and cost ca 40€) the serviceman sent me the following picture and **told me that the keyboard is OK but the SSD has to be replaced** (ca 270€):

[image]

**He was not able to tell me more details about the tests he ran** (except that they were "professional tests"). He also was not able to explain precisely what the problem with the SSD is and how it can be related to my keyboard problem, which is the only problem that I have ever experienced. He was also **refusing to do anything with the keyboard** and was not able to tell me if he had a look at it or not. I decided to **get the laptop back without him doing anything.**

After I obtained the laptop, it **didn't boot to Grub2 as before** but directly to the Windows bootloader (Windows 10 was preinstalled on the laptop when I bought it but I rarely use it). The serviceman didn't know how to repair it and gave it to me to **do it myself** (which I managed to do with the help of a live USB). He claimed that he didn't fiddle with the system anyhow and that he only **exchanged my SSD for his test SSD and then put my SSD back.**

It is also strange that **he wanted to know my admin password** from the very beginning. **I gave it to him** because I keep passwords in Bitwarden and all sensitive data in encrypted folders and I thought that I should trust a registered service if I give them my laptop anyway. I realize now, of course, that he could have installed a keylogger or use my emails (I do not have to enter passwords in my Thunderbird and hence they are probably stored somewhere in text files or in a wallet which is automatically opened).

I have mixed feelings and don't know what to do. I will most likely just order a spare keyboard and laptop tools and exchange the keyboard myself.

**I have the following questions:**

1. Can you conclude from the picture that the SSD has to be replaced?
2. Can a faulty SSD have any effect on the function of the keyboard columns without having any other recognizable effect?
3. Is it possible that the servicemen just exchanged the SSD's and the rewriting of the MBR was initiated automatically, e.g., by BIOS, after this? If not, what did he most likely do?
4. Is it customary that a serviceman asks for the admin password if the client comes with a hardware problem? How would you react?

Answer (score 1):

(1) No.

(2) Yes, via the Operating system and drivers.

(3) You need to ask Lenovo Support .

(4) Yes - they need to start the computer.  I have had service on my Lenovo Computer at a bona fide Lenovo Service Center. They do need the password and I signed a release. I set up a special admin userid for them and tested it. I did not give them my main userid or password.

You need to be in control of the service process.

Comment: Also.. have you tried an EXTERNAL keyboard?  Does that work without issues? .. that should answer your questions faster than anything else.  I myself wouldn't trust the repairman you are dealing with.